# Listview in xamarin form not using full space of form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms cross platform app. I have a form where i need to show data in listview.

Data is displaying but its not using entire space resulting in keeping unwanted space at bottom.

[image]

my xaml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BMTHomesApp.Views.ImportantAppointments">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" RowHeight="100" HeightRequest="-1" x:Name="ListViewAppointments" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="20,0,0,0" ColumnSpacing="20">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <!--<BoxView Color="#f7f7f7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                <BoxView Color="#ffffff" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>-->
                                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ImageAppointmentIcon" Source="AppointmentsIcon.png" Aspect="AspectFit"></Image>
                                <Label TextColor="#00344e" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Subject}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="End"></Label>
                                <Label TextColor="#0073ae" Text="{Binding StartDate}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActLoder"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Color="#ffffff" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be the ActivityIndicator after the ListView. They are enclosed inside a StackLayout so will both take up space vertically.

If you want the ActivityIndicator to appear over the top of the ListView, replace the StackLayout with a Grid.

Not sure what the HeightRequest=-1 is there for.

Comment: I set HeightRequest=-1 to see whether by using this it will use form height but didn't work... also even if I remove activity indicator .. then also same result

Comment: Get rid of both the activity indicator and the stack layout and see if the listview takes up the whole page. Also you should either set HasUnevenRows = true OR RowHeight=100 you don't need both.

Comment: Probably RowHeight=100 seeing how you have hard coded your row heights.

Comment: The trick to working out what is taking up space is to set each controls background color to something garish. So ContentPage, StackLayout, ListView, ActivityIndicator. What color is the space?

Comment: Try setting StackLayout VerticalOptions to FillAndExpand

Comment: Thanks @steve , removing HeightRequest=-1  ,HasUnevenRows = true and setting stacklayout and well as ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" , solved problem

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use **BindableLayout** feature? Since Xamarin Forms 3.5 you can Bind a list in a Stack Layout for example, you have much more control than using ListView like this:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfObjects}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label  Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>
            <Label Text="{Binding Status}" ></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the `StackLayout` is causing your layout issue. You are stacking the `Listview` ontop of an `ActivityIndicator`

If you want the `ActivityIndicator` to appear in the same space as the `Listview` but centered then you can try the following:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" RowHeight="100" x:Name="ListViewAppointments" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="20,0,0,0" ColumnSpacing="20">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!--<BoxView Color="#f7f7f7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            <BoxView Color="#ffffff" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>-->
                            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ImageAppointmentIcon" Source="AppointmentsIcon.png" Aspect="AspectFit"></Image>
                            <Label TextColor="#00344e" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Subject}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="End"></Label>
                            <Label TextColor="#0073ae" Text="{Binding StartDate}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"></Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActLoder"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Color="#ffffff" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```